# BATHTUB FAUCET LEAK, MOEN

Tags: leak, faucet, bathtub

I put a replacement cartridge in mu Moen Bathtub faucet only to make the leak worse. I used a No. 1225 i see 1220 is interchangeable plus cost $5. less.

the  only thing we did not spray with Lyme away and grease the new cartridge a  it is leaking worse than before

Comment: are you sure that you used the correct replacement cartridge?

Comment: Contact Moen https://www.moen.com/customer-support/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=&utm_content=&utm_term=&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIr8bOgNb-2wIVD7jACh20DgOPEAAYASABEgJqcfD_BwE many times parts are free.